# Is it more efficient to write to a file in one statement than multiple statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I'm running loop that writes around 10000 lines to a file. I've been searching but can't find whether it's more efficient to concatenate a string in a write statement, or use multiple write statements. ie:

```
f = open(fileName,"w+")

for item in list:
    f.write(str1 + str2 + str3 + item + "\n\n")
```

or

```
f = open(fileName,"w+")

for item in list:
    f.write(str1)
    f.write(str2)
    f.write(str3)
    f.write(item)
    f.write("\n\n")
```

Is the first or second option more efficient?

I imagine this has been asked before and I'm asking the question in a strange way, so if someone can point me in the right direction that'd be fantastic!

Comment: You may want to check that for yourself with this module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: Concatenating strings is not very efficient in `str1 + str2 + str3 + item + "\n\n"`. For that, you should probably be using `join()`

Comment: For 10000 this is almost certainly a micro-optimisation, but a valid question nonetheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour for the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) method, when not specifying a buffering mode, is to follow the system default which is usually line-buffered. Which means that Python will flush the output to the file (i.e. do a write operation), for every new-line it finds.

So I would presume in this example that both operations, as far as file IO performance is concerned, are equivalent, seeing as the new-line character is the last thing output.

Comment: That's in terms of buffered writing. I suspect there's some balance between string concatenation and multiple method calls that might become important if the data was _massive_. Probably it doesn't matter for most examples :)

Comment: Certainly, yes. I'm not sure how Python internally deals with adding things to the buffer with sequential `write` calls, whether that is more efficient than doing string concatenation and outputting it all at once.